# how to unit test the backbone success and error response on save using jasmine

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jasmine, jasmine-jquery, jasmine-node

```
 onSaveEvent: function (event) {
                if (this.model !== null) {
                    var that = this;

                    this.model.save(this.model.toJSON(), {
                        success: function (model) {
                            that.model = model;
                            that.model.attributes.isDirty = false;
                        },

                        error: function (model, xhr) {
                            that.model.attributes.isDirty = true;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

how to unit test the model's save' success and error responses in Jasmine?

Answer (score 2):

To test this without a fake server  you can test that the function was binded to the model an then call the binded function by yourself. In other words mock out the ajax save part out of the model.

```
var view = new YourView()
jasmine.spyOne(view.model, 'save')
view. onSaveEvent()
var args = view.model.save.mostRecentCall.args

args[1].success()
expect(view.model.attributes.isDirty).toBeFalsy()

args[1].error()
expect(view.model.attributes.isDirty). toBeTruthy()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sinon.js to create a fake server for your tests.

http://sinonjs.org/

Example code:

```
  describe("when saving a user model", function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
      this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
      this.responseBody = '{"name":"test user","id":1,"title":"tester"}';
      this.server.respondWith(
        "POST",
        "/user",
        [
          200,
          {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
          this.responseBody
        ]
      );
      this.eventSpy = sinon.spy();
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      this.server.restore();
    });

    it("should not save when name is blank", function() {
      this.user.bind("error", this.eventSpy);
      this.user.save({"name": ""});

      expect(this.eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnce();    
      expect(this.eventSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(this.user, "cannot have a blank name");
    });

    it("should call the server", function() {
      this.user.save();
      expect(this.server.requests[0].method).toEqual("POST");
      expect(this.server.requests[0].url).toEqual("/user");
      expect(JSON.parse(this.server.requests[0].requestBody)).toEqual(this.user.attributes);
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need sinon to emulate server responses. This library has utilities like this:

```
 this.server.respondWith("GET", "/episode/123",
      [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      '{"id":123,"title":"Hollywood - Part 2"}']);
```

So whenever you have a Model with the root episode and id 123, sinon will return this on a fetch call.

Read this:
http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/03/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon.html

**Update**: Adding a second workaround as asker request. Mocking save method.

//Use this in your tests instead of Backbone.js Model

```
var ExtendedModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    //mocked save:
    save : function(data, options){
         if( data ){
             this.set(data);
         }
         var mocked = this.toJSON();
         if( !mocked.id ){
             mocked.id = new Date().getTime();
         } 
         mocked = this.parse(mocked);
         if( options.success ){
             options.success(this);  
         } 
         if( options.error ){
             options.error(this);  
         } 
    }
});

var MyModel = ExtendedModel.extend({
});
```

However I'm still suggest you to use Sinon. Mocking the Backbone.js is not ellegant and also support header response codes and other stuff is also more complex and a kind of reinvent the wheel. While with sinon you just need to add the library an create server response.

Comment: I am using the following technologies backbone.js, require.js, jquery, Rest services over WebAPI. from jasmine, I am mocking the model object and binding to a view for unit testing. when I get the response from the view to the mock model, how to unit the model's save (sucess, error) responses. isn't there a way to unit test the model responses without sinon.

Comment: Sinon is just other JavaScript lib, not sure why you cannot add it. But anyway, other workaround is to overwrite save method. I will add that workaround in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I like going through sinon here, afterall the ajax call is made by backbone, not by the unit you are testing, here is my solution

```
    var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
      success_callback : function (model){
        this.model = model;
        this.model.attributes.isDirty = false;

      },
      error_callback: function (model, xhr){

      },
      onSaveEvent: function (event) {

        this.save([], {
            success: _.bind(this.save_success, this),
            error: _.bind(this.error_callback, this);
        });
    });


    var callback_invoker = function(type_str, which_argument) {
      this.which_argument = which_argument || 0;
      this.type_str = type_str;
      var func = function() {
        var options = arguments[this.which_argument] || {};
        if (this.type_str == 'success') {
          var run = options.success || function() {};

        }else if (this.type_str == 'error') {
          var run = options.error || function() {};
        }
        run();
      };
      this.function = _.bind(func, this);
    };

    it('save success calls callback', function() {
      instance = new Model();
      spyOn(instance, 'save_success');
      spyOn(_,'bind').andCallThrough();
      var invoker = new callback_invoker('success', 1);
      spyOn(instance, 'save').andCallFake(invoker.function);
      instance.onSaveEvent();
      expect(_.bind).toHaveBeenCalledWith(instance.save_success, instance);
      expect(instance.save_success).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```